# Incrementing cell row in excel

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm that's going to submit data from the fields to columns A, B, and C, but I need it to move down and fill in the next empty row every time a user hits submit.

This is what I have so far, I don't know what I would put in to make it so it would go from A2/B2/C2 to A3/B3/C3, etc.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
   Dim LastRow As Object

   Set LastRow = Sheet1.Range("a65536").End(xlUp)

   Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = MatchNum.Text
   Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = TeamNum.Text
   Sheet1.Range("C2").Value = AllianceTeamNum.Text

   MsgBox "One record written to Sheet1"

End Sub
```

I'm a complete beginner at Visual Basic (approx. 1 hr. of experience) and it'd be nice if the solution is as simple as possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The solution involving the fewest changes to the current code seems to be to somehow make use of that nice-looking `LastRow` object; which currently isn't being used for much other than to hang on to some memory. Have you tried incorporating `LastRow` into the three ranges which get populated?

Comment: If you don't mind the records being in reverse order you can just insert the record at the top shifting everything down. Saves working out what row to write too. Probably not as fast as appending it to the bottom though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    With Sheet1
        .Select

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A" & LastRow).Value = MatchNum.Text
        .Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TeamNum.Text
        .Range("C" & LastRow).Value = AllianceTeamNum.Text

    End With
    MsgBox "One record written to Sheet1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Dim start As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim LastRow As Object

   Set LastRow = Sheet1.Range("a65536").End(xlUp)

   Sheet1.Range("A" & start).Value = "a"
   Sheet1.Range("B" & start).Value = "b"
   Sheet1.Range("C" & start).Value = "c"

   MsgBox "One record written to Sheet1"

   start = start + 1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   start = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this address the "empty row" part of the question?