# VBA textbox to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a input user form in excel where a user enters data into a three different textbox. This is my code

```
      Private Sub Process_Click()

     Worksheets("1").Range("A1").Value = Date.Value
     Worksheets("1").Range("B1").Value = Name.Value
     Worksheets("1").Range("C1").Value = Amount.Value


     End Sub
```

So the first time I press process it will write the data into those cells A1,b1, and C1. What i want to do is that everytime I open the form and click process on my form I would like for those values to go down a row for example the next time i click process it will go to A2,b2,and c2, and so on.

Comment: similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375767/incrementing-cell-row-in-excel/15377059#15377059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to Barranka's answer.

The basic idea is the same. You check for the last-populated row, and append your data one row lower than that.

The method used here to find the last-populated row might be slightly more efficient than using a `while` loop, but you should test both to see for yourself:

```
Private Sub Process_Click()
    Dim appendRow As Long

    ' add 1 to get the row after the last-populated row
    appendRow = Worksheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(XlUp).Row + 1

    Worksheets("1").Range("A" & appendRow).Value = Date.Value
    Worksheets("1").Range("B" & appendRow).Value = Name.Value
    Worksheets("1").Range("C" & appendRow).Value = Amount.Value
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know which was the last filled cell. This can be done easily navigating the range. Assuming that all three columns are filled with data, you can read only one (let's say `A`) to get the last row:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 1
while Worksheets("1").Range("A" & i).Value <> "" or Worksheets("1").Range("A" & i).Value <> 0
    i = i + 1
wend
```

Now that you know the last row populated:

```
 Worksheets("1").Range("A" & i).Value = Date.Value
 Worksheets("1").Range("B" & i).Value = Name.Value
 Worksheets("1").Range("C" & i).Value = Amount.Value
```

It's just a way to solve it, and it works if your data set is not meant to be really big. Downside is, if you have a very long table, the `while` can take some time to track the last populated row.

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks, what if you want to start at lets say row 7 instead of the first

Comment: @JacobRuvalcaba the example I provided to you has all you need to know. It's up to you to adapt it to your needs (this site is suposed to give you orientation, not to make the work for you). I suggest you to read this article: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/